# Picking up object in Unity Quest makes me zoom around my gamespace

Tags: unity-game-engine, quest

I think it has something to do with trying to fix an object's collision. I have a box collider on a cube, and when I pick it up, sometimes I go zooming around (even can use it to move vertically!). It's annoying and not sure how to fix this.

Upon letting go of the object, there are no more issues.

Comment: Can you provide some of the code used for picking up the object and the collision callbacks?

Comment: I'm using the Unity Grabbable OVR script.

Comment: are you using OCRPlayController? the collider on the object you pick up is colliding with the player controller and pushing you back. You can probably yse the physics matrix to disable collision between you are the items you pick up.